# count where different is more than 2 days

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have this code that I would like to get the total of log that is closed.

> **(A)** More than 2 days.
>   **(B)** Less than 2 days.

```
for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m) {

   $next_year = $cur_year + 1;
   $monthName=date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)).'';
   $monthNumber  = date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
   $monthName  = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
   $currentMonthText = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
   $nextMonthText    = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 1));

   $result= $DB->query("SELECT * FROM ".$DB->prefix("calldesk_log")." 
   WHERE MONTH(date_open)='$monthNumber' AND date_open >=  '$currentMonthText'
   AND date_open <  '$nextMonthText' AND status='Closed'") or die(mysql_error()); 


    while($row = $DB->fetchArray($result))
    {
       $id_report=$row['id_report)'];
       $date_open=$row['date_open'];
       $date_close=$row['date_close'];
       $diff = abs(strtotime($date_open) - strtotime($date_close));
       $min = floor($diff / (60*60*24)); 
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If its only a matter of days differences, let MYSQL do the job using [DATE_ADD() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp), you will thus avoid classical date mistakes which are obvious in your actual code (leap years, year change, etc...)

Here are some examples depending on what you want to do , which is unclear...

---

Logs that are between 2 days in the past and 2 days in the future (if that's possible but this what you do in your code)

```
SELECT * 
FROM ".$DB->prefix("calldesk_log")." 
WHERE date_open BETWEEN DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
                    AND DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL  2 DAY)
  AND status='Closed'
```

---

Logs that are between current date and 2 days in the future

```
SELECT * 
FROM ".$DB->prefix("calldesk_log")." 
WHERE date_open BETWEEN curdate()
                    AND DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL  2 DAY)
  AND status='Closed'
```

---

Logs that are between 2 days in the past and current date

```
SELECT * 
FROM ".$DB->prefix("calldesk_log")." 
WHERE date_open BETWEEN DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL  -2 DAY)
                    AND curdate()
  AND status='Closed'
```

---

If you want to count months instead of days, just change the INTERVAL:

```
DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL  -2 MONTH)
```

---

If you want to take the time into account, use `NOW()` instead of `curdate()`:

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL  -2 DAY)
```

---

That's it, you can do all this in pure SQL and let MySQL do the job for you.